# combine the null columns to get desired concat in query

Tags: mysql, sql, coalesce

if my table looks like :

| id | name | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | kasis | Nepal |
| 2 | samika |  |
| 3 |  | Australia |

How can I combine it to get something like :

| Concatenated(Desired) |
| --- |
| 1,kasis,Nepal |
| 2,samika |
| 3,Australia |

```
select id || coalesce(name,'') || coalesce(country,'') from Emptable;
```

gives me :

| Concatenated(Error) |
| --- |
| 1kasisNepal |
| 2samika |
| 3Australia |

with no comma separation.
(In **oracle,mysql**)

Comment: `coalesce(name || ',', '')`

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL use

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', id, name, country)
FROM Emptable;
```

This functions skips NULLs rather that CONCAT().

---

In Oracle use, for example,

```
SELECT id || ',' || TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM name || ',' || country)
FROM Emptable;
```

The query assumes that either `name` or `country` is not NULL.

Comment: what about Oracle ?